# Couldn't find GaBadge with 'id'=3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error couldn't find id with id = '' i dont know how to fix it if any know how to fix it please tell me

```
@req2 = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@req)
  #@req3 = JSON.parse(@req2)

  #@reqId = @req3
  @reqId = @req2[0]
  @req3 = JSON.parse(@reqId)

  @req3.each do |item|
    @id = item['id']
    @id = GaBadge.find(@id)
    if @id.present?
      @id.destroy
    end
    #@obj = @id.destroy
  end
```

Comment: So is it id=3 or id=''?

Comment: it is id = 3 getting id in console but sending error

Comment: "if any know how to fix it" - make sure that badges exist for those ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add .int and fixed
 @req3.each do |item|
    @id = item['id']
    @ga_badge = GaBadge.find_by_id(@id.to_i)
    unless @ga_badge.nil?
      @ga_badge.destroy
    end
  end

Answer (score 0):

Error says GaBadge's table not having any record with id = 3, use

`GaBadge.find_by_id(@id)`

it will return nil instead of error.
Change your loop to

```
  @req3.each do |item|
    @id = item['id']
    @ga_badge = GaBadge.find_by_id(@id.to_i)
    unless @ga_badge.nil?
      @ga_badge.destroy
    end
  end
```

Comment: same error after using @id = GaBadge.find_by_id(@id.to_i)

Comment: no same error after using @id = GaBadge.find_by_id(@id.to_i)

Comment: i think this problem is from top  
 #    @req = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body)
    #

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are assigning value to @id as string.
Just try this,

```
@id = GaBadge.find_by_id(@id.to_i)
```

Comment: It is method to convert string/float values to integer.

Comment: same error after using @id = GaBadge.find_by_id(@id.to_i)

Comment: Can you please share your console log.

Comment: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

Comment: is your if condition is working fine? Because your are checking it for present right and if it present then it must get destroy. Check your if condition.

Comment: if condition not find id

Comment: please give me your skype account

Comment: id is not present in if condition

Comment: skype name: - navin.puttewar
you can also search it by my number 8149204983